# jquery toggle not working correctly in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, slidetoggle

I have a `toggle` function which is defined to show/hide a div when some an item is clicked.
this function is being called in a `fancybox`.
the first time that fancy is called an load every thing is normal an correct, by when i close the fancy an reopen it, and the click the item, the item that should be showed is being twinked(show and hide)..

i tried these codes:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-descriptor');
    var $t = $('#field_'+selector);

    if ($t.is(':visible')) {
        $t.slideUp();
    } else {
        $t.slideDown();
    }
});
```

---

and this:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-descriptor');
    $('#field_'+selector).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

I can't understand what is the problem!?

special thanks to anyone who can give me some help :)

=======
Edited:

**fancy initialization:**

```
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        /*maxWidth  : 1000,
        maxHeight   : 600,*/
        fitToView   : false,
        width   : '80%',
        height  : '60%',
        autoSize    : true,
        openEffect  : 'fadeIn',
        closeEffect : 'fadeOut',
        scrolling   : 'no',
        helpers:  {
            title  :  {
                type : 'inside'
            },
            thumbs : {
                width: 50,
                height: 50
            },
            overlay : {
            css : { 
                'overflow' : 'hidden' ,
                'background' : 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'
            }
            }
        }
    });
```

**html code**

```html
<li id="coreValues_wrapper">
<span data-id="4" data-descriptor="coreValues" id="label_coreValues" class="add coreValues">
core values
</span>
<div style="display:none;" data-id="4" data-descriptor="coreValues" id="field_coreValues" class="coreValues">
<textarea id="value_coreValues" required="required" maxlength="300" class="input-block-level data"></textarea>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Could you show your fancybox initialization script as well as your relevant html code?

Comment: Where are you registering your .add click event? Does it get registered every time you display the fancy box?

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz yes! i've writen it in fancy opening.. is it wrong?

Comment: @JFK question edited.

Comment: @parisssss you do not want to declare the click event on fancy box opening. If you do it that way, it will declare the click event every time you open the fancy box and it will cause inconsistency in your click events. You might want to move it out of the fancy box opening and instead of doing 'on', you should use 'live' event. If you use .live event, every dom element added after the click event declaration will have that click event attached to them as well. So it will look like this $(document).live("click", ".add", function(){

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz : `.live()` is deprecated, use `.on()` instead (in its delegated form if you need so)

Comment: @parisssss : I don't see any html code with a `.fancybox` *class* selector

Comment: @JFK i have a button which has the `fancybox` class, when clicked the other html code is called (in ajax mode) which i wrote in the question.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/dL86ucnk/1/ and compare.